# Nokogiri can't get g tags from svg

Tags: ruby, svg, nokogiri

I have a svg file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" height="700" width="1024" viewBox="0 0 1024 700" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" text-rendering="geometricPrecision" image-rendering="optimizeQuality" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g id="L_691200_group">
<g id="L_691200_background">
<path stroke-width="5" fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="black" d="..."/>
</g>
<g id="L_691200_path"><path d="..."/></g>
<g id="L_691200_icon"><circle cx="387.413" cy="485.451" r="7.99993" stroke-width="1" stroke="black"/><circle cx="478.876" cy="379.327" r="2.50001" stroke-width="1" stroke="black"/><circle cx="276.717" cy="593.047" r="2.50001" stroke-width="1" stroke="black"/></g>
<g id="L_691200_symbol">
<path fill="white" fill-rule="nonzero" d="..."/>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

I tried to parse it in Ruby using Nokogiri but I cannot get the g tags.

I tried various things:

```
groups = doc.xpath('//g')
groups = doc.xpath('//xmlns:g')
groups = doc.xpath('//g', 'g' => 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')
groups = doc.css('g')
```

But groups is always empty. The only way I got it to work was to remove namespaces from doc. But I can't do it that way since I need to save the document again after changing a few thins.

How can I get the g tags without removing the namespace?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Ups seems I forgot it. I added it.

Comment: Have you noticed that the g tags are nested? Do you want the outer one, or the inner ones, or all?

Comment: Assuming you will filter your nested `g`s later: `doc.at 'g'`.

Comment: Do you know for sure that the document is being parsed correctly? Try `puts doc.to_s`, which should show the XML. I've had it before where I've incorrectly instantiated the document, and it's provided an empty XML as a response.

Comment: @sawa I only wan't the inner ones but I don't care if the outer one is included since I'm going to edit them based on their ids.

Comment: @joonty I'm positive that it is parsed correctly otherwise removing namespaces shouldn't work either.

Comment: @Eschon sorry, missed that at the end there

Comment: @mudasobwa `doc.at 'g'` gives me the following array `[ "id", "L_691200_group" ]` which is not what I need.

Comment: @Eschon `doc.css("g")` works for me - which version of Nokogiri are you using?

Comment: @Eschon `doc.at 'g'` gives you the first met instance of `Nokogiri::XML::Element`, not an array.

Comment: @joonty "Do you know for sure that the document is being parsed correctly?" Using `doc.to_s` isn't the way to  see if there are errors as Nokogiri will attempt to fix the document if it can't parse, and big documents can be exhausting to check manually because humans suck at looking at freeform text and finding inconsistencies. Instead let Nokogiri *show* the errors: [`doc.errors`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Document:errors) returns the errors found in the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have an induced error. I will post this as an answer for a sake of code formatting.

```
▶ Nokogiri::VERSION
#⇒ "1.5.4"

▶ xml = Nokogiri.parse '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>...'
▶ xml.xpath('//xmlns:g').size
#⇒ 5
```

Besides that, `xml.css 'g'` works the same way.

Comment: Ok that really works I had an error in my code later on that made me think it was not working. My own stupidity got me again